# Find the mean from the mode and variance

Tags: statistics

What data value is 2.5 standard deviations above the mean in a data set with mode=60 and variance=64? Answer: 90.

If the answer is 90, and 2.5 standard deviations is 20, then the answer implies the mean is 70.

*How does one find that the mean is 70 with this information?* Frankly, I thought the answer is that you can't.

The mode is the most common value. It gives some information, but does not tell us where the mean is. (Or so I thought.)

Comment: Without knowing additional information (distribution?), you cannot answer the question. Intuitively, mode is not enought:  if $X$ is continuous random variable with density $f$, you can put mode at any $x$ you want by setting $f(x)$ extremely high (because set of only 1 point has measure $0$).

Comment: That's certainly what I thought. But the question says the correct answer is 90. It must just be a very poorly designed question.